# Different behaviors with same time complexity

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I am solving the following question on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/factor-combinations/description/):

> Write a function that takes an integer n and return all possible combinations of its factors.  For e.g., `12` should return: 
>       [
>           [2, 6],
>           [2, 2, 3],
>           [3, 4]
>       ]

I came up with the following approach (in C++):

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> getFactors(int n) {
        if(n==0 || n==1) return vector<vector<int>>();

        vector<vector<int>> result;
        vector<int> factors;
        getFactorsUtil(result, factors, n, 2);

        return result;
    }

    void getFactorsUtil(vector<vector<int>>& result, vector<int>& factors, int n, int start) {
        long int each=1;
        for(int i=0; i<factors.size(); i++)
            each = each*factors[i];
        if(each==n) result.push_back(factors);
        if(each>n) return;

        for(int i=start; i<=n; i++) {
            if(n%i==0) {        //perfectly divisible
                factors.push_back(i);
                getFactorsUtil(result, factors, n, i);
                factors.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This works as expected, but times out on the last test case: `23848713`.

One of the accepted and upvoted solutions (in Java) is as follows:

```
public List<List<Integer>> getFactors(int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    helper(result, new ArrayList<Integer>(), n, 2);
    return result;
}

public void helper(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> item, int n, int start){
    if (n <= 1) {
        if (item.size() > 1) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(item));
        }
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            item.add(i);
            helper(result, item, n/i, i);
            item.remove(item.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

The time complexities of both the codes are same (in my opinion).  Why then does *my code* fail and the other code run successfully on `23848713`?  I mean, is there some apparent bug in my code, or is it some problem with the online judge?

I appreciate your help.

**Edit**: There was no `<=n` in my `for loop condition` in the code earlier (just because the other code has it - it is not actually needed as per the question).  I included it later.  But anyway, it still times out.

**Edit2**: In big-O notation, we skip the co-efficients of `n`.  I think that is the reason it breaks here.  My code has large values of these constants.  I can come up with no other explanation.

Comment: Why downvote?  Care to explain?!

Comment: Sorry, questions of the form "Here's my code, please figure out what's wrong" are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JimGarrison, and I believe that is because people do not do any _research_.  However, in this case, I have.

Comment: As far as I know, the OP's question is perfectly valid for this site. That having been said, one reason it might be downvoted is because it's the sort of problem that regular use of a debugger might solve, which is typically a reason questions get downvoted. Also, the OP has tagged their question with both `C++` and `Java` tags, which is a big no-no unless your question involves interop between those two languages (and this definitely isn't that).

Comment: @Xirema, thank you.  It touches the grey area.  But the question is such!  Also, I tagged C++ and Java since codes are in those languages.  I can go ahead and remove Java.

Comment: Two notes: 1. Your algorithm produces the wrong output. 2. `helper(result, item, n/i, i);` scans significantly fewer at each call than  `getFactorsUtil(result, factors, n, i);` because of the `n/i`, so they do not have the same time complexity.

Comment: @user4581301, thanks for your idea..

Comment: I have to walk back the second part: plotting the curves of the time spent really similar. Your suspicion about the discarded coefficients looks closer to  correct. When I run I run test code with easily divisible numbers, the similarity really stands out, but also runs out of RAM. On third thought, what we really want is the worst case when computing Big O. Best case was similar. Worst case I didn't plot.

Comment: @user4581301, thank you for your analysis.  Yeah, that's the reason I asked on SO.  I just wanted to confirm if my suspicion was right or wrong.  But thanks to your earlier comment, I got the idea about what the issue might be.  I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the first loop (in which I calculate the product of all the numbers in `factors` into `each`), my code was higher than a magnitude of `O(n)`.  Due to this, it failed.

However, when I called it with the value `n/i` (and not `n`), I could completely get rid of the O(n) factor by elimination the entire loop.  This is so because I no longer had to check if the product was equal to `n`.

Thus, the code finally got accepted because of this change.  Thanks.

(Posting as it might be helpful to someone).  Also, thanks to `@user4581301` for the hint which eventually led me to it.